# Please explain the following code

Tags: java, file, jfilechooser, filereader

```
public void open()
{
    int returnVal = jfilechooser.showOpenDialog(jf); //jf is JFrame's reference
    if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
    {
        //to erase any text in the text area before adding new text
        jtextarea.setText(null);
        try
        {
            String fileName = jfilechooser.getSelectedFile().getPath();
            String show=jfilechooser.getSelectedFile().getName();
            Reader in = new FileReader(jfilechooser.getSelectedFile());
            char[] buff = new char[100000];
            int nch;
            while((nch = in.read(buff, 0, buff.length)) != -1)
            jtextarea.append(new String(buff, 0, nch));
            String fileContent = jtextarea.getText();
            jf.setTitle(show+" : S-Textpad");
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException x)
        {}
        catch(IOException ioe)
        {
            System.err.println("I/O Error on Open");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain what you think it does & where you are confused.  In the latter case, support your query with any relevant quotes from the JavaDocs.  It would also be advisable to ask a specific question, given this is a Q&A site.

Comment: As an aside, some good reasons not to study that code too closely, or at least not to emulate it.  1) Ignoring exceptions. 2) I/O with no `finally`. 3) Odd and inconsistent attribute nomenclature.  4) Choosing a `String` representation of a  `File` then using the `String` for a reader.  5) Unbracketed loop with the loop statement unindented. 6) Declaring the otherwise unused `fileContent` attribute.  7) Perhaps more I missed..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it:

- opens a File Chooser dialog so the user can select a file
- if the user did not click Cancel, if then reads the file contents
- then it appends that content to a text area
- and finally sets the frame title to the selected filename plus a static string

However I don't know if the code compiles and there is at least a useless line:

```
String fileContent = jtextarea.getText();
```